# java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: connect

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm using JDBC in my program, but not able to connect to oracle database. I'm getting java.net.BindException on the line

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@"hostName":"port":"sid", "username", "password");
```

Though I'm able to connect to database using same credentials into SQL Developer

Here's the full stacktrace

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:743)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:666)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:566)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at configuration.DBManager.getConnection(DBManager.java:17)
    at configuration.Configuration.main(Configuration.java:45)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:470)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:506)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:595)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:230)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1452)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:496)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:161)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:159)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:428)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: You've run out of local ports. You've somehow created thousands of TCP connections within two minutes Try to taper off. Use a connection pool.

Comment: can u suggest me how to use a connection pool in jdbc

Comment: Have a look at Apache DBCP.